# Really weird substr behavior in PHP, inconsistent outputs

Tags: php, substr

So I have this code:

```
$phone1="‭1234567890‬";

$phone2="1234567890";

$phoneformat1 = '('.substr($phone1, 0, 3).') '.substr($phone1, 3, 3).'-'.substr($phone1,6);

$phoneformat2 = '('.substr($phone2, 0, 3).') '.substr($phone2, 3, 3).'-'.substr($phone2,6);

echo $phoneformat1 . "<br>";

echo $phoneformat2;
```

and this is the output:

```
(‭) 123-4567890‬
(123) 456-7890
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on here? Why is the same code giving inconstant outputs? You can test this out at http://phptester.net

Answer (score 5):

Since the real value of first one is `$phone1="\U+202D1234567890\U+202C";` and the second is `$phone2="1234567890";`.

It might be usefully to check the value by using online tools which shows also non-printable characters like [this](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php), to make sure that value is the "real one" or with some extra characters.

Comment: Might give more info like what that is and how you found it.

Comment: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202d/index.htm - this is a special character, for test you can copy value from the second one to the first one and it will work the same, will gave you the same result. I catch that copying it to my terminal which shows me also hidden chars, probably somehow you put this value wrongly or copied it wrongly, not sure. It's strictly the problem with value not with php.

Comment: I’m not OP I know what it is and how to see it. I’m telling to add to your answer.

Comment: I'm curious here. I know the characterencoding stuff, unicode, utf-8 with dynamic bits based on character etc etc but how do you know that it is used in this example without guessing?

Comment: Sure, sorry. Added more precisely answer.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld In my way of thinking about that was that it can't be something wrong in php function - not in that case. That's why i firstly checked the values as probably was the bed one.